# how this language is not recursive?

Tags: grammar, automata

This question was asked at Gate 2009. I don't understand how it's not recursive?

> L = {A<sup>m</sup> B<sup>m</sup> C A<sup>n</sup> B<sup>n</sup> | m, n ≥ 0}
>   L' = {A<sup>i</sup> B<sup>j</sup> C<sup>k</sup> | i, j, k ≥ 0}

Why is language {L intersection L'} not recursive?

Comment: @Phrogz :) well i dnt know how to explain it more neatly..

Comment: What are `A`, `B`, and `C`?

Comment: What grammar is this? PEG? BNF? What is "Gate 2009" and how does it pertain to this question? Simply tagging this with "automata" does not seem to be sufficient background for someone to understand the context in which you are asking this question.

Comment: This looks recursive to me. We must be missing something vital.

Comment: @Phrogz it is a complete question ...

Comment: @AnshikaAgrawal The downvotes indicate that others do not share your belief that it is a complete question. I advise you to edit and expand upon it, providing background on the question, and perhaps adding what you have thought about it so far.

Comment: Try asking this at [computer science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Since "recursive" is a general category of language that includes all simpler classes of language, the question is probably meant to be understood as why the given language is something simpler than a recursive language—say, that it is a type 1, 2, or 3. Otherwise the question makes no sense (since it's clearly recursive.)

The answer can be found by looking at the intersection:

> L ∩ L' = {A<sup>m</sup> B<sup>m</sup> C | m ≥ 0}

This is just the language of all balanced parentheses followed by C, which can be recognized by a deterministic push-down automaton and hence is a context-free language.